Chrome browser page reloads when executing a Save or Save As using The File System Access API
I created a test html/js program (using VS-Code and Go Live) that simply increments some state variables that I could Save, Save As, and Open/Load to experiment with The File System Access API. When I Save, or Save As, the Chrome browser page reloads and resets the state variables back to their initial values of zero (not the values at the save event time). This problem does not occur when I Open/Load and read the state data from a local file – not sure why? The current state data is actually saved even though the page is reloaded and the state data is reset to initial values as shown below
let state = {
    arr: [0],
    dataA: 0,
    dataB: 0,
    dataC: 0,
    fileHandle: null
}

When I simply made a copy of the test project folder and ran the program from the new copied folder, everything worked (Save, SaveAs, Open Load) without reloading the browser page – still not sure why? I then add this fs code to project and page reload problem occurred again whenever I tried to save or Save As. Again, data was saved, but Chrome browser reloaded, and state values were reset to initial values.
GitHub Link: https://github.com/Quercus-Alba/fs-access-api-example

you forgot to show how you are calling these functions

I meant in the question - where code can be read without an eye hernia

Sorry about that! Here is GitHub link: https://github.com/Quercus-Alba/fs-access-api-example

Partial solution: I discovered with the help of a family member, that when using VS-Code with Live Server, the saved JSON file must be stored outside the project folder that is opened in VS-Code. This is probably why the code worked without a page reload when I copied the folder – I was reading the JSON file from the original folder and not the copied folder. Further experiments showed that if I saved the JSON file anywhere else on my local computer (other than the project folder) the program worked without reloading the browser page.

I’m still unclear if the page-reload problem is particular to just VS-Code or Live Server (or both working together), and if the problem occurs in other integrated development environments (IDEs). Please let me know if you have further insights related to this problem.

I discovered when using Live Server (by Ritwick Dey) in VS-Code that files in the public folder (that reside within the root project folder) need to be ignored by Live Server. This is accomplished by creating a settings.json file within the .vscode folder. For an example of how to create a setting.json file, see link: https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/HEAD/docs/faqs.md.
Below are the liveServer.settings I used to resolve the page reload problem.
Project_root_folder/.vscode/setting.json
{
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles" : [
        ".vscode/**",
        "public/**"
    ]

}

